# nVidia 331.49 Installaton on P151EM1 Clevo (with dual-boot Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, 13.10

(apologies for the possibly confusing title)

Here is the situation:
I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on my P151EM1 Clevo laptop (GTX670MX) (dual boot with W7).
I'm trying to update the drivers to version 311.49, but I am constantly running into strange issues.

Installed manually (via .run download from nVidia's site), ended up with a black screen and a black "X" as a cursor, AFTER the "Ubuntu" loading screen appears. (installing via the Ctrl+Alt+F1 Terminal).

Installed via the xorg-edgers ppa, ended up with the same issue (black screen and black "X" as cursor).

My Ubuntu 13.10 is pretty much a new installation, it is fully updated too. Only additional thing I have installed is OpenJDK 7 JRE.

NOTE: I'm new at trying to do this (first time seriously considering using Ubuntu for any of my games that support it, example: Minecraft. Which runs perfectly fine yet it uses the onboard HD4000 which isn't ideal. Making it run worse than in Windows 7).

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 6 years.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing bumblebee, as this seems to have helped many others with the latest nvidia drivers.

Boot into the command line then run:

$  `sudo apt-get remove --purge bumblebee`

Reboot and you should have a working X

Comment: I currently have anything nvidia uninstalled, so is Bumblebee what came with the xorg-edgers driver download? Because I think I tried removing that, though I'll try again just in case.

Comment: Ok I installed from the xorg-edgers ppa, removed Bumblebee. Still running into the same issue. I have noticed it must be loading to the desktop (program problem message or something, that appears when I login without nvidia drivers. So it isn't related)